# What would be the best way on Azure to consume a range of MQTT topics from 1-2 external MQTT brokers?

Tags: azure, mqtt, azure-eventhub

We are setting up a PoC for a data platform for a bus company, aiming to use Event Hubs for event sourcing. Our partners are collecting a lot of MQTT topics from our vehicles and bridging them on EMQ X / Mosquitto, and we basically need to mirror those data onto our platform.

It seems that IoT Hub can't subscribe to those brokers(?). Is there any easy, managed solution we can use to fetch the data and ingest them on Event Hubs? We're low on dev resources, so we're currently not able to develop our own solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, we built a microservice around the MqttNet library. The service basically does two things:

1. Subscribing to external topics and publishing all events on Event Hubs for the different topics. Internal services subscribe to these.
2. Subscribing to an Event Hub where all internal services publish their events, then publishing them as MQTT topics for ecternal consumers.